# angularjs function in controller function

Tags: angularjs

In my angularjs , i have some functions in controller function, like below.

```
$scope.TestFn = {
    Detail: function() {
        console.log('in Detail function');                          
        },
    LIBset: function(index) {
        console.log('in LIBset function');
        $scope.SelRow = index;
        },
    LibSplit: function() {
            console.log('in LibSplit function');    
            // Some Code                    
        }
}
$scope.EleFn = {
    Comments: function() {
            console.log('in function Comments');
            //some code                 
        },
    Implement: function() {
            console.log('in function Implement');
            //some code     
        }
}
```

First set of functions ($scope.TestFn) i am using in first htm template like below,

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in TestFn.LibSplit() track by $index">
        <td><input type="text" class="inputtxt" ng-model="x"></td>
</tr>
```

And other set ($scope.EleFn) i am using in other html template. When I click on link to load first template it works fine, but when I click on seocnd link to load second html template, the function "LibSplit" is called unnecessarily. I clearly do not have call for this function in my second html template. And when i click on second link again, this function is not called. My observation is, the unwanted call to this libsplit function happens only when i click first then second link.

What could be the reason for such angular behavior and how to fix this ? Also please let me know what we do call this kind of function arrangements.

I wish I could create a plunkr or jsfiddle but i am not sure whether I would be able to reproduce the problem or not.

Thanks

Comment: you shouldn't use functions to dynamically create arrays for `ng-repeat`, it uses `$watchCollection` (a watcher) to detect changes in the collection. Therefore any change you make will trigger your function. Try initialising the array instead: `$scope.array = $scope.TestFn.LibSplit();` with `ng-repeat="x in array ..."`

Comment: Hi @Aleksey, i changed as you suggested but it didn't work. I took out the function and created as $scope.LibSplit and called in  ng-repeat="x in LibSplit but still getting same behavior.

Comment: Thansk @Aleksey, I removed the controller function and moved the filter logic to model and it solved the problem. Your comments really helped to understand.